# Given a set of simple graph coordinates inside a square, how to identify all base polygons?

Tags: r, geometry, coordinates

I have a 4x4 square within which one can draw lines either vertically or horizontally in units of 1. The result would look something like this (as an example).

[image]

Given this problem, how would one go about identifying the 3 polygons that construct this image?

I understand that the large square in which the pieces lie is a polygon too, but I'm only interested in the 'base' polygons - not sure if that's the right way to call them.

Clarification: We only know the coordinates of the lines from inputting them, we don't know the polygons in advance.

The solution accordingly would be the polygons themselves (in pseudo-code):

```r
pol[1] = c(0, 0),
         c(1, 0),
         c(1, 1),
         c(2, 1),
         c(2, 2),
         c(1, 2),
         c(1, 3),
         c(0, 3),
         c(0, 0)


pol[2] = c(1, 0),
         c(3, 0),
         c(3, 4),
         c(0, 4),
         c(0, 3),
         c(1, 3),
         c(1, 2),
         c(2, 2),
         c(2, 1),
         c(1, 1),
         c(1, 0)

pol[3] = c(3, 0),
         c(4, 0),
         c(4, 4),
         c(3, 4),
         c(3, 0)
```

Comment: Sorry. What exactly do you want? Do you want people to create an R object that describes the polygons?

Comment: Looking more for direction regarding the methodology to do so. I wouldn't expect anyone to create an R code for this on my behalf.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach to create the spatial object in R. `pol_sf` is the final output, which is an `sf` object. This approach needs the `sf` package. The `tidyverse` package is not required but work well on the `sf` object.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

# Polygon 1
pol1 <- st_polygon(list(rbind(c(0, 0),
                              c(1, 0),
                              c(1, 1),
                              c(2, 1),
                              c(2, 2),
                              c(1, 2),
                              c(1, 3),
                              c(0, 3),
                              c(0, 0))))

# Polygon 2
pol2 <- st_polygon(list(rbind(c(1, 0),
                              c(3, 0),
                              c(3, 4),
                              c(0, 4),
                              c(0, 3),
                              c(1, 3),
                              c(1, 2),
                              c(2, 2),
                              c(2, 1),
                              c(1, 1),
                              c(1, 0))))

# Polygon 3
pol3 <- st_polygon(list(rbind(c(3, 0),
                              c(4, 0),
                              c(4, 4),
                              c(3, 4),
                              c(3, 0))))

# Combine pol1, pol2, and pol3
pol_sfc <- st_as_sfc(list(pol1, pol2, pol3))

# Create an sf object
pol_sf <- tibble(ID = c("a", "b", "c")) %>% 
  mutate(geometry = pol_sfc) %>%
  st_as_sf()

# Plot the data
ggplot(pol_sf) + geom_sf(aes(fill = ID))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey www, I feel bad because my original question might not have been clear. The problem is that although we know all the coordinates, we don't know the polygons in advance. The problem is less about showing the polygons in a graph and more about an algorithm that can tell these polygons apart just from coordinates (and then maybe plot them similarly to how you have done it as the cherry on top).